# How to update the code of Laravel that is deployed on live server?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

The Laravel project made based on vuejs UI is deployed on the server. Now I need to change the code and worked fine on the local machine. But the problem arose that I have to zip all the files and again upload. This seemed tedious. Also when I uploaded it, the application seemed not changed as on the local machine. What should I do? I also don't have a node installed on my Cpanel so that I was unable to run npm run dev.

Comment: Hi Anurag! You should look into using a repository like Github.com or similar to manage your code. The downside is you will likely need root access to the server, so a virtual private server is needed unless you can get root access to your shared hosting server. Laravel projects are a little difficult when they are hosted on shared servers. I would seriously consider porting it to a VPS and you can go with something like Linode or Digital Ocean where you pay only $5 a month. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @Savlon, do you know what is changed while we run command npm run dev so that I could only copy that file and change the files on the server?

Comment: Npm compiles frontend assets, so you might get away with copying the entire public folder over as it should contain everything updated.

Comment: It is often compiled to a file at: `/public/js/app.js` for the JS, and `/public/css/app.css` for CSS. But this will depend on your configuration. You could simply build locally and transfer that file using FTP. I would advise to use `Git` or another VCS however. Consider building the assets on the server, especially if you're working in a team.

Answer (score 1):

**The preferred way is to use a Version Control System (VCS) like `Git`.**

**VCS**

Version control systems are software tools that help software teams manage changes to source code over time. Consider uploading your project to a [Github](https://github.com/) repository.

If you Google this, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

**Note:** You require `SSH access` to the server in order to run `Git` commands. Having `SSH access` will also solve your problem of not being able to run commands like `npm run dev`. Consider deploying your repository on a Virtual Private Server (VPS).

**(S)FTP**

There are several ways of deploying. One of them being, manually transferring files using `SFTP` or `FTP`. However, as you've mentioned, this is a tedious process.